# Can you mix custom-view and non-custom view components in a single UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I have a multi-component UIPickerView in my application.  Two components are plain and completely served by the `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` method.    My third component however requires a custom view via the `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` method.    I don't see any way in the documentation to  have a "partially customized" UIPickerView where some components use `...titleForRow...` and some use `...viewForRow...`.   Is this possible?    If so, how does one do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to go all or nothing.  The plain, boring default views are pretty much just a UILabel. You should be able to easily recreate this view.

Comment: I suspected as much, thanks.   I did so (created custom UILabel's), and found I also had to set the UILabel background color to transparent or else  the UILabel's solid background didn't jive properly with the gradient background of the parent picker, resulting in unpleasant artifacts.